# Slide Out Box Menu | Github slider | How to auto slide these sliders

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://github.com/codrops/SlideOutBoxMenu/  I have used the github slideoutbox how to autoslide these images please need your help thanks.

They have used

imagesLoaded by Dave DeSandro
TweenMax by Greensock

Please check this link https://github.com/codrops/SlideOutBoxMenu/

```
{
// The Slide (Product) class.
class Slide {
    constructor(el, settings) {
        this.DOM = {el: el};

        this.settings = {
            detailsEl: null,

            onHideDetails: () => {return false;}
        }
        Object.assign(this.settings, settings);

        // The slide´s container.
        this.DOM.wrap = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.slide__wrap');
        // The image element.
        this.DOM.img = this.DOM.wrap.querySelector('.slide__img');
        // The title container.
        this.DOM.titleWrap = this.DOM.wrap.querySelector('.slide__title-wrap');
        // The details boxes.
        this.DOM.detailsItems = Array.from(this.settings.detailsEl.querySelectorAll('.details__item'));
        this.totalDetailItems = this.DOM.detailsItems.length;
        // The details box that has the close control. When clicking on it call the onHideDetails passed in the initialization options.
        this.DOM.hideDetailsCtrl = this.DOM.detailsItems.filter(item => item.classList.contains('details__item--close'))[0];
        this.DOM.hideDetailsCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.settings.onHideDetails());
        // Some config values.
        this.config = {
            animation: {
                duration: 1.2,
                ease: Expo.easeInOut
            }
        };
    }
    // Sets the current class.
    setCurrent(isCurrent = true) {
        this.DOM.el.classList[isCurrent ? 'add' : 'remove']('slide--current');
    }
    // Hide the slide.
    hide(direction) {
        return this.toggle('hide', direction);
    }
    // Show the slide.
    show(direction) {
        this.DOM.el.style.zIndex = 1000;
        return this.toggle('show', direction);
    }
    // Show/Hide the slide.
    toggle(action, direction) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // When showing a slide, the slide´s container will move 100% from the right or left depending on the direction.
            // At the same time, both title wrap and the image will move the other way around thus creating the unreveal effect.
            // Also, when showing or hiding a slide, we scale it from or to a value of 1.1.
            if ( action === 'show' ) {
                TweenMax.to(this.DOM.wrap, this.config.animation.duration, {
                    ease: this.config.animation.ease,
                    startAt: {x: direction === 'right' ? '100%' : '-100%'},
                    x: '0%'
                });
                TweenMax.to(this.DOM.titleWrap, this.config.animation.duration, {
                    ease: this.config.animation.ease,
                    startAt: {x: direction === 'right' ? '-100%' : '100%'},
                    x: '0%'
                });
            }

            TweenMax.to(this.DOM.img, this.config.animation.duration, {
                ease: this.config.animation.ease,
                startAt: action === 'hide' ? {} : {x: direction === 'right' ? '-100%' : '100%', scale: 1.1},
                x: '0%',
                scale: action === 'hide' ? 1.1 : 1,
                onStart: () => {
                    this.DOM.img.style.transformOrigin = action === 'hide' ? 
                                                            direction === 'right' ? '100% 50%' : '0% 50%':
                                                            direction === 'right' ? '0% 50%' : '100% 50%';
                    this.DOM.el.style.opacity = 1;
                },
                onComplete: () => {
                    this.DOM.el.style.zIndex = 999;
                    this.DOM.el.style.opacity = action === 'hide' ? 0 : 1;
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    // Show the details boxes.
    showDetails() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // If open already then do nothing.
            if ( this.isDetailsOpen ) {
                resolve();
                return false;
            }

            // We want to achieve here the same reveal/unreveal effect of the slideshow.
            // The item animates from 100% to 0% (top,bottom,left or right) while its inner element does the reverse movement.
            const processItem = (item,pos) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    // The duration and easing for the last 3 elements will be different to create a different feeling for the animation.
                    const duration = pos >= this.totalDetailItems-3 ? 0.7 : 0.2;
                    const ease = pos >= this.totalDetailItems-3 ? 'Expo.easeOut' : 'Power2.easeInOut';
                    // Every box will have a delay. 
                    const delay = pos*0.08;
                    // The direction to animate the box. We can specify this as a data attribute otherwise we assume a default of rtl ("right to left")
                    // right to left (rtl) | left to right (ltr) | bottom to top (btt) | top to bottom (ttb).
                    const direction = item.dataset.direction || 'rtl';

                    let itemAnimOpts = {
                        ease: ease,
                        delay: delay,
                        x: '0%',
                        y: '0%'
                    };

                    let innerAnimOpts = {
                        ease: ease,
                        delay: delay,
                        x: '0%',
                        y: '0%',
                        onComplete: resolve
                    };

                    if ( direction === 'rtl' || direction === 'ltr' ) {
                        itemAnimOpts.startAt = direction === 'rtl' ? {x: '100%', y: '0%'} : {x: '-100%', y: '0%'};
                        innerAnimOpts.startAt= direction === 'rtl' ? {x: '-100%', y: '0%'} : {x: '100%', y: '0%'};
                    }
                    else {
                        itemAnimOpts.startAt = direction === 'btt' ? {x: '0%', y: '100%'} : {x: '0%',y: '-100%'};
                        innerAnimOpts.startAt = direction === 'btt' ? {x: '0%', y: '-100%'} : {x: '0%', y: '100%'};
                    }

                    TweenMax.to(item, duration, itemAnimOpts);
                    TweenMax.to(item.querySelector('.details__inner'), duration, innerAnimOpts);
                });
            };

            // Process each one of the boxes..
            let processing = [];
            this.DOM.detailsItems.forEach((item,pos) => processing.push(processItem(item,pos)));
            Promise.all(processing).then(() => {
                this.isDetailsOpen = true;
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
    hideDetails() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if ( !this.isDetailsOpen ) {
                resolve();
                return false;
            }

            const processItem = (item,pos) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const duration = pos === 0 ? 0.7 : 0.2;
                    const ease = pos === 0 ? 'Expo.easeOut' : 'Power2.easeInOut';
                    const delay = (this.totalDetailItems-pos-1)*0.08;
                    const direction = item.dataset.direction || 'rtl'; // right to left (rtl) | left to right (ltr) | bottom to top (btt) | top to bottom (ttb).

                    let itemAnimOpts = {
                        ease: ease,
                        delay: delay
                    };

                    let innerAnimOpts = {
                        ease: ease,
                        delay: delay,
                        onComplete: resolve
                    };

                    if ( direction === 'rtl' || direction === 'ltr' ) {
                        itemAnimOpts.x = direction === 'rtl' ? '100%' : '-100%';
                        itemAnimOpts.y = '0%';
                        innerAnimOpts.x= direction === 'rtl' ? '-100%' : '100%';
                        innerAnimOpts.y = '0%';
                    }
                    else {
                        itemAnimOpts.y = direction === 'btt' ? '100%' : '-100%';
                        itemAnimOpts.x = '0%';
                        innerAnimOpts.y= direction === 'btt' ? '-100%' : '100%';
                        innerAnimOpts.x = '0%';
                    }

                    TweenMax.to(item, duration, itemAnimOpts);
                    TweenMax.to(item.querySelector('.details__inner'), duration, innerAnimOpts);
                });
            };

            let processing = [];
            this.DOM.detailsItems.forEach((item,pos) => processing.push(processItem(item,pos)));
            Promise.all(processing).then(() => {
                this.isDetailsOpen = false;
                resolve();
            });

        });
    }
}
```

This above code they have used for the slider . So I want to slide automatically.

Comment: Can you please share your code here, its not recommended to provide external links. Please attach a minimal verifiable example in the question itself.

Comment: Hi I have added the code about could you help ..